# Poetry trips itself up with package updates

Tags: python, python-poetry

The following command in a Dockerfile:

```
poetry install --only main -E deploy
```

Will *sometimes* fail to run on github CI due to the package's .dist-info directory not being found. We simply re-run the job and it passes next time. However this has been happening with increasing frequency, and it's getting annoying.

We have around 30 packages in the repo, and it can happen on any of them, seemingly at random, and always resolved once we re-run.

Only just today I noticed that this happens when the package has been updated as part of the installation.

In the example below, poetry fails to install `pathspec` because it's looking for `platformdirs-2.6.0.dist-info` which will not exist because poetry previously updated it to `platformdirs` to `3.5.1`.

However, it is trying to install `pathspec` *after* `platformdirs` - so I'm wondering whether this is a concurrency issue?

Using poetry 1.3, which should include two fixes related to concurrency issues:

- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/6186
- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/6471

Posting on SO rather than github as they want you to confirm you're using the latest version when raising issues, but unfortunately it's not easy for us to upgrade, plus I actually prefer SO format.

[image]